# help Add Any Application Shortcut in Desktop Context Menu

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu

[i got the info here](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/add-any-application-shortcut-in-desktop-context-menu) but after adding that i didn't get any shortcut on my desktop contest menu :(
 pls help me  i want it only on my desktop context menu

> 1. Open regedit and goto:
>
> CODEHKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
>   now under this key create another key
>   with any name and in right-side pane
>   set its value to the label, which you
>   want to show in desktop context menu,
>   like Media Player, Winamp, Firefox,
>   anything else.
>
> 2. Now create another key under this newly created key with name command.
>      and in right-side pane set its value
>      to the exact path of application,
>      like:
>
> C:\Program Files\Windows Media
>   Player\wmplayer.exe C:\Program
>   Files\Winamp\winamp.exe etc...
>
> 3. Thats it. Now you can check your favorite application shortcut in
>      desktop context menu.
> 4. You can create as many shortcut as you want. Simply create a separate key
>      for all the applications.
> 5. Following is a ready-made code:
>
> CODEWindows Registry Editor Version
>   5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WMP]
>   @="Windows Media Player"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WMP\command]
>   @="C:\Program Files\Windows Media
>   Player\wmplayer.exe" Just change the
>   label and path to ur desired
>   application and save with the name
>   "vishal.reg" (including the quotes)
>   and run it.
>
> U can also set the application
>   shortcut to show only when u press
>    key by adding "Extended"
>   String value in right-side pane of the
>   newly created key:
>
> CODEWindows Registry Editor Version
>   5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WMP]
>   @="Windows Media Player" "Extended"=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WMP\command]
>   @="C:\Program Files\Windows Media
>   Player\wmplayer.exe"

Comment: English? (15 chars)

Comment: @hello71 what ?

Comment: i what it only on my desktop context menu? Did you mean "want"?

Answer (score 3):

Only Windows Vista and Windows 7 support adding menu entries via this registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\
```

Prior to this (e.g. Windows XP), menu entries could only be added to `Directory\Background` via `shellex`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\
```

`shellex` is exponentially more difficult to use, because it requires you to write your own COM DLL, presumbling using C++, and register it with the system.  This is no easy feat for an armchair registry hacker.

So basically, you can't easily do what you're trying to do.  At least not in WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Windows XP, the simplest way to do this is to download and install TweakUI from Microsoft.  It's one of the Windows XP PowerToys, available at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx.

Once you run TweakUI, click "Templates" in the list on the left.  You can enable/disable existing templates or add new ones.